# printing a Windows user control form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, namespaces

I am working on a project for printing the layout I create using a user control form.

I have my printer setup and everything. However, what I essentially want to do is to use the coordinates of the elements.

How can I access the elements of the user control form inside my project and assign the value of the fields accordingly?

I have two namespaces in my project
1. Display the user control form as Windows desktop application - MyForm
2. Interacts with printer and fetch data from the database. MyForm.Core

MyForm is the application and MyForm.Core is implemented as a library.
Please let me know how I can access the user form on MyForm namespace in MyForm.Core?

I included the MyForm namespace in the printer.cs

```
using MyForm;
```

And tried to get an object of the User Form Layout.cs as:

```
var layoutObj = new Layout();
```

But the Layout is not included and shows its not found. Alternatively, I tried including MyForm namespace.

```
using MyForm;
```

and tried

```
var layoutObj = new MyForm();
```

but Visual studio shows me a message MyForm is a namespace but is used like a type.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I moved the user control under the MyForm.Core NameSpace and now can access it without problems.